# R prop table of numeric data

Tags: r

I've searched and tried a bunch of ways to get at this, but am not finding a way to do it.

Assuming the `mtcars` data set, what I'd like to do is create a prop table that looks like the below (note that percentages below are totally made up):

```
    disp
gear  0+  100+  200+  300+  400+
   3 20%   20%   20%   20%   20%
   4  0%   25%   25%   25%   25%
   5  0%   10%   20%   30%   40%
```

The solution needs to put `disp` into bins, label the bins and then create a prop table based on the relationship between the `disp` bins and `gear`.

I'm sorry there is no sample code, but I'm coming up blank on how to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these values correct? Perhaps `100*prop.table(table(transform(mtcars[c('gear', 'disp')], disp=cut(disp, breaks=c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400,Inf), labels=c('0+', '100+', '200+', '300+', '400+')))),1)`

Comment: Sorry, no, those values are 100% made up. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: How important is the precise formatting?  By default, `cut` uses `(0,100]` as the label.  In addition, by default, `prop.table` does not format with percent signs.  By relaxing those restrictions, the code gets much simpler.

Comment: My audience (and most audiences) won't know what `(0,100]` means intuitively. And the percents are absolutely critical. You wouldn't tell someone that you traveled 2.5 today, so why would you put a percentage in front of someone without a percent sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cut` to produce bins and `sub` to rename them

```
mtcars$dispR <- as.character(cut(mtcars$disp,breaks = seq(0,500,100),right=FALSE))
mtcars$dispR <- sub("\\[(\\d{1,3}).*","\\1+",mtcars$dispR)
```

Then, to add the proportion, we can use `questionr::rprop`

```
library(questionr)
rprop(table(mtcars$gear,mtcars$dispR))


               0+    100+  200+  300+  400+  Total
  3          0.0   6.7  33.3  33.3  26.7 100.0
  4         33.3  66.7   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0
  5         20.0  40.0   0.0  40.0   0.0 100.0
  Ensemble  15.6  34.4  15.6  21.9  12.5 100.0
```

This second step may be done in base R with `addmargins`

```
t <- addmargins(table(mtcars$gear,mtcars$dispR))
round(t/t[,"Sum"] * 100,1)

        0+  100+  200+  300+  400+   Sum
  3     0.0   6.7  33.3  33.3  26.7 100.0
  4    33.3  66.7   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0
  5    20.0  40.0   0.0  40.0   0.0 100.0
  Sum  15.6  34.4  15.6  21.9  12.5 100.0
```

Comment: Do you know why `?lprop` redirects to `rprop` with no explanation or mention of `lprop`?

Comment: The base R solution isn't working, not sure if you tested it. I don't need it, but don't want to approve with a non-working solution for someone else to stumble across. For the base R solution, would it be easier to wrap prop.table around the table output? Or does that not give the same solution?

Comment: The output isn't correct. Check the cut intervals of `df$disp[df$gear == 3]` to test against your first row.

Comment: @PierreLafortune - I'm not sure I understand why you think it is incorrect?

Comment: @PierreLafortune thanks. I added `right=FALSE` in `cut`

Comment: @JohnTarr it is an alias, probably for linguistic reasons. r for row, l for ligne (row in french). I changed it in my edit

Comment: @JohnTarr There are 15 cars with 3 gears. 5 of them are within 300-400 displacement. `5/15 = .33` not `.40` as the output suggests.

Comment: @JohnTarr also, I tested the base-R solution and it works, providing you did the first step (cut and sub). I made it clear in my edit

Comment: @scoa - Thanks for the clarification on the `rprop` vs. `lprop`. Is there somewhere with a clear explanation of `cut`'s `right=FALSE/TRUE`? I was playing around with `cut` and don't understand how it determines where to bin items? I'm accepting your corrected answer, since `lprop` lets me get %'s and totals, but you may want to consider fixing/removing the `addmargins` bit.

Comment: @JohnTarr `?cut` has an explanation. `right=FALSE` includes the lowest bound and excludes the highest bound, `right=TRUE` does the opposite

Answer (score 3):

```
disp <- paste0(findInterval(mtcars$disp, c(seq(0,400, 100),Inf)), "00+")
round(prop.table(table(mtcars$gear, disp), 1)*100, 1)
#    disp
#     100+ 200+ 300+ 400+ 500+
#   3  0.0  6.7 33.3 33.3 26.7
#   4 33.3 66.7  0.0  0.0  0.0
#   5 20.0 40.0  0.0 40.0  0.0
```

Comment: What accounts for the difference in your results vs. @scoa?

Comment: He didn't account for the default behavior of `cut`